# Roll up time stamp to capture specific time every day in bash script

Tags: linux, shell, timestamp, sh, rollup

I have bash script file -->  there i have a variable 'startTs' which i would like to capture current day 12:01 AM (PST) in Milliseconds.

Expectation --> pass 'startTs' value as current day 12:01 AM time stamp in milliseconds

Could you please share the expression how can i auto roll up this startTs variable every day.

```
Ex : 
2021-11-15 ---> startTs= 1636963260 (2021-11-15 : 12:01 AM)
2021-11-16 ----> startTs= 1637049660 (2021-11-16 : 12:01 AM)
2021-11-17 ----> startTs= 1637136060 (2021-11-17 : 12:01 AM)
2021-11-18 ----> startTs= 1637222460 (2021-11-18 : 12:01 AM)
etc
```

Comment: What do you mean by rolling up a timestamp?

Comment: rolling up means pass 'startTs' value as current day 12:01 AM time stamp in milliseconds

Comment: @tink - rolling up means pass 'startTs' value as current day 12:01 AM time stamp in milliseconds